No need to prove the continuity for $e^x$?
I've read the wikipedia article of "Limits of rational exponents". And it says the real exponents are defined as the limit of rational exponents. So, for a positive real number $b$ and any abitrary real number $x$, $b^x$ is well-defined continuously, is what they say. In short, is the exponential function defined as a continuous function by design? You don't need to prove its continuity because it's already continuous?

@YvesDaoust Yes, he mentions this, but it doesn't mean it is not defined by a power series in the course. I would assume it is.

@DietrichBurde I don't think so. It is possible (I do it in my courses) to define real exponential without power series, and then prove the power series representation as a theorem. IMO it is much more natural than taking the Taylor expansion as a definition. On the other hand, complex exponential is indeed usually defined as a power series, but that makes perfect sense, because this is a generalization of the real case.

OP, there is still something that we need to prove. I assume the definition goes like this: if $x_n\to x$ where $(x_n)$ is a sequence of rational numbers then we define $b^x=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} b^{x_n}$. It can be proven that the limit exists and doesn't depend on the sequence, so the definition makes sense. However, for continuity we need the limit to hold for all real sequences $x_n\to x$, not just rational ones. So it has to be proven that this holds for real sequences as well, which is not part of the definition anymore.

The article says that the rational exponential, the exponential defined on the rationals, is extended by continuity on the real line by
$$ b^x=\lim_{r(\in \mathbb Q)\to x}b^r. $$
There is a list of things that should be proved:

The function is well-defined: you need to show that the above limit exists, since it might not be the case. The proof might in principle split into the cases $x\in \mathbb Q$ and $x\in\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q$.
Consistency: you might want to show that the above definition is actually extending the rational exponential, so when $x\in\mathbb Q$ you recover $b^x$. Luckily, this is a consequence of the previous point.
Continuity:

You need to show that the limit exists without the restriction $r\in
   \mathbb Q$
You need to show that the limit coincides with the value of the function at the point $x$ (this will be actually a consequence of the definition of the function and all the previous points).



I will not give details on the proof, since this is not what you are asking, I found this post which gives what looks like a partial answer. In any case, the above points are definitely not an immediate consequence of the definition. There is definitely a few things to check to ensure that the definition is well-posed and the resulting function is continuous.

There's a general approach going on here:

you define a function, let's call it $p_1: \mathbb Q \to \mathbb R$, where $p_1(x) = 2^x$ (I'm using "2" as an example here). The right-hand side is defined for integer $x$, and then using various bits of cleverness, for all rational $x$.

You show that $p_1$, as a function from the rationals to the reals, is continuous. That's a bit of a pain, but it can be done.

You apply a general theorem: if $A$ is a dense subset of $B$, and $f : A \to \mathbb R$ is uniformly$^{*}$ continuous, then there's a unique function $g: B \to \mathbb R$ such that (a) for $x \in A$, we have $g(x) = f(x)$, and (b) $g$ is continuous. In simpler words: any continuous function $f$ on a dense subset admits a unique continuous extension on the whole set.  Applying this theorem to $p_1$ gives you a continuous function $p_2: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ with the property that $p_2(x) = p_1(x)$ for $x \in \mathbb Q$, as desired.

If $q_1, q_2, \ldots$ is a sequence of rationals that converges to a rational $q$, then by continuity of $p_1$, you know that $$p_1(q) = \lim_{n \to \infty} p_1(q_n).$$ But because $p_2$ and $p_1$ agree on $\mathbb Q$, you also know that $$p_2(q) = \lim_{n \to \infty} p_2(q_n).$$

On the other hand, if the sequence of $q_i$s converges to a non-rational, $s$, then continuity of $p_2$ (on all of $\mathbb R$!) once again ensures that $$p_2(s) = \lim_{n \to \infty} p_2(q_n).$$

Indeed, if $r_1, r_2, \ldots \in \mathbb R$ converges to $r$, we have $$p_2(r) = \lim_{n \to \infty} p_2(r_n),$$ so the various concerns expressed in the comments about different kinds of limits are all taken care of by continuity of $p_2$.


The good news is that the general theorem is not too hard; it appears early in most topology texts.
Post-comment addition
The bad news is that I stated the theorem wrong --- you need uniform continuity. (Thanks, Lukas Heger, for pointing that out).
To make the result work with this more restrictive (but correct!) theorem, I'll consider an interval of the form $I_n = [n-1, n+1]$ where $n$ is an integer. Such an interval is compact (by Heine-Borel) so continuity and uniform continuity are the same thing. So now we know that there's a unique continuous extension of $p_1$ on such intervals. And the same is true for intervals of the form $[n, n+1]$. By considering $I_1$ and $I_2$, we can see that the extensions of $p_1$ for these two intervals can each be restricted to the (unique!) extension on $[0, 1]$, hence they must agree on that interval. A similar argument shows that the extensions on all possible $I_n$ agree on their overlaps, giving a function on all of $\mathbb R$ that extends $p_1$.
An alternative approach is to find a continuous extension over $[0, 1]$, and then note that for $x \in [1, 2]$, we have
$$
p_1(x) = 2 * p_1(x-1)
$$
and therefore define $p_2$ on $[1, 2]$ by
$$
p_2(x) = 2 * p_2(x-1)
$$
A similar trick lets us define $p_2$ on the interval $[2, 3]$, etc.

It's not true that a continuous function on a dense subset always admits a continuous extension: consider for example $x \mapsto 1/x$ defined on $(0,1) \subset [0,1]$.

Oops. I need "uniformly continuous". I'll edit.

I'm afraid your edit doesn't quite work either: Heine-Borel applies to $[n-1,n+1]$, but not to $[n-1,n+1] \cap \Bbb Q$ and a priori, our function is only defined on the latter. It seems to me that one has to show "by hand" that an exponential is uniformly continuous on $[n-1,n+1] \cap \Bbb Q$ for this approach.

Yeah...you're right, of course. It turns out that remembering stuff I knew 40 years ago isn't as easy as it once was. :(  I feel as if uniform continuity on an interval like [0, 2] should actually be relatively simple: if you have an $\epsilon-\delta$ proof of continuity at $x = 0.5$, for instance, almost the same proof should work at $x = 1.5$, except with $\delta$ changed to something like $\delta/2$, because $f(1.5) = 2 f(0.5)$  (I'm still using $f(x) = 2^x$ here). Of course, you need something a bit larger than 2 in the denominator, etc., etc.

The idea with uniform continuity is nice. There should be an elementary way of showing that $p_1$ is locally Lipschitz, because a posteriori one knows that the derivative of $b^x$ is $\log(b)b^x$, which is locally bounded.

I agree, Lorenzo. In fact, I was thinking that on the interval $[0, 1]$, say, we know that the "derivative" is at most $\log 2$, which we could overestimate as $1$. So to do an eps-delta continuity proof, choosing delta = epsilon should suffice.
